# 2 slide shows on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to make 2 slide shows of img on the same page. I have it so that one will work, but can not get the second on to work. Please help. If you need I can post the CSS for the whole thing as well. Thank you.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Colorado Marauders</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen">
 <script language="JavaScript">
    function mdy(todaysdate) 
       {
        return todaysdate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + todaysdate.getDate() +       "/" +       todaysdate.getFullYear();
       };
       mdy(new Date());
function slide(id, intval, total) {
    var image = document.getElementById(id),
        imgcount = 1;
    image.src = "image/" + id + imgcount + ".jpg";
    return window.setInterval(function() {
        if (++imgcount > total) imgcount = 1;
        image.src = "image/" + id + imgcount + ".jpg";
    }, intval);
}
window.onload = function()
{
var slider1 = slide('img', 3000, 8);
var slider2 = slide('c1', 4000, 22);
};
  </script> 


</head>
<body >  
<header>
<div class="title">
<h1>Colorado Marauders Disk Golf</h1>
</div>
<h3 class="event" style="text-align:center;"><a href="events.html">Events</a></h3>
</header>
<section>
<div class="content"></div>
<div><img src="image/main.jpg" style= "width:33em; height:auto; margin-right: .1em; 
margin-top: 1.9; border-color:white; border-style:solid; border-radius:50%; border-
width:.1em; float:left; height:auto; box-shadow: .6em .6em .6em red;"></img></div >
<div class="top">
<div id="container" >
<img id="img" src="image/img1.jpg" />
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Check out the pictures from our last event.</h1>
</div>

</div >
</section>
<section>
<table>
<tr>
<h3 class="Tmain">
Top 10 Tag holders
<div class="tag">
<ol>
<li style="color: white;">Shawn Gould</li>
<li style="color: white;">Josh Cain</li>
<li style="color: white;">Adrian Meyer</li>
<li style="color: white;">John Allen</li>
<li style="color: white;">Mike Brown</li>
<li style="color: white;">Marcus Moreno</li>
<li style="color: white;">Cameron Palen</li>
<li style="color: white;">Tyler Moffitt</li>
<li style="color: white;">Raymond Lewis</li>
<li style="color: white;">Connor Madsen</li>
</ol>
</div>

<h3 class="Bmain">
Other stuff for the group
</h1>
</h1>
</tr>
<tr>
<h1 class="Tmain2">

</h1>
<h1 class="Bmain2">
news
</h1>
</tr>
<tr>
<h4 class="Tmain3">
<div>
<a href = "mailto:coloradomaraudersdiskgolf@gmail.com?subject=Request to     
join"/><img     
style="height:21.3em; width:33.1em;" src="image/c1.jpg"/>
</div>
</h4>
<h1 class="Bmain3">
<div  style="text-align:center;">
Here are some other link that you might like.
</div>
<div class="fb">
Like us on <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Colorado-Marauders 
/297312640455928?skip_nax_wizard=true&ref_type=logout_gear" target="_blank"><img 
src="image/facebook.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<div  class="fb1">
<a href="http://www.discraft.com/" target="_blank"><img src="image/discraft.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<div  class="fb2">
<a href="http://www.dgcoursereview.com/" target="_blank"><img src="image/dg.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<div class="fb3">
 <a href="http://www.innovadiscs.com/" target="_blank"><img src="image/innova.jpg"
/></a>
</div>
<div class="fb4">
 <a href="http://www.vibramdiscgolf.com/" target="_blank"><img  
src="image/vibram.jpg"    
/></a>
</div>
<div class="fb5">
 <a href="http://www.mvpdiscsports.com/" target="_blank"><img src="image/mvp.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<div class="fb6">
 <a href="http://www.pdga.com/" target="_blank"><img src="image/pdga.jpg"/></a>
</div>
</h1>
</tr>
</table>
</section>
<footer>
<h3>
Colorado Marauders 
<date><script language="JavaScript">
sampleDate1=new Date()
document.write (mdy(sampleDate1))
 </script></date>
 </h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please format your code...! It's unreadable in it's current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should have had a look on your console!**

1) First error is `TypeError: slideA is not defined` because it's defined inside the setInterval.

2) Don't declare multiple functions with same name!

3) There's no need to define `slideA` multiple times. Once defined you can call it as often as you need by passing the target element as argument. I pass the interval time as a second argument so each slider can have its own speed.

4) Better than `body.onload` use the `window.onload` event to avoid errors if images are not completely loaded.

First remove `onload="slideA()"` from `<body>`, then your code should look like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function mdy(todaysdate) {
    return todaysdate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + todaysdate.getDate() + "/" + todaysdate.getFullYear();
   };
   mdy(new Date());
// here the global vars imgcount and total are removed, each slider has its own

// now define function slide, first arument is id of element its applied to,
// second is the interval in ms, third is the total amount of imgs
function slide(id, intval, total) {
    // define vars outside setInterval, otherwise it's always repeated
    var image = document.getElementById(id),
        imgcount = 1;
    image.src = "image/" + id + imgcount + ".jpg"; // setup the first image
    // return the interval so it becomes stopable
    return window.setInterval(function() {
        if (++imgcount > total) imgcount = 1; // increase and compare imgcount in one line
        // since imgcount is always increased second compare (< 1) can be omitted
        image.src = "image/" + id + imgcount + ".jpg";
    }, intval);
}
// when window is loaded start the slider
window.onload = function() {
    // start first slider by calling function slide and store it in a variable
    var slider1 = slide('img', 3000, 8);
    var slider2 = slide('c', 4000, 22); // same with second slider
};

</script>
```

Now if you want to stop the first slider you can simply do (inside the window.onload):

```
window.clearInterval(slider1);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: So I have made all the changes as you posted, and now none of the sliders work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong at this point.

Comment: @WayzoftheKomodo Oh, sorry, I used `setTimeout` but it should be `setInterval`. See my edit and try again. If there's still a problem please tell exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have made the change to the script and the top pic slide is working. The second one is still not doing anything but sitting there. No change or anything it just sits there with the default image. I am getting and error in my JS that says "TypeError: image is null on CMDG.html:16" I have looked at the code and there does not seem to be anything wrong with it, so I am not sure why it is giving me this. But again the first slide is working just fine. Thank you for that.

Comment: @WayzoftheKomodo That error sounds as if an image-tag with `id='c'` (= id used in second slider) doesn't exist. You should check what id the img-tag of second slider has in your html (maybe `'pic'`?) and use that id in `var slider2 = ( ... )`.

Comment: Ok I am now lost...I am going to update the code in the top with the code that I have now. If you could point out what I am missing that would be cool. Because I have looked all over and think I am just seeing to much HTML to find what I am missing at this point.

Comment: @WayzoftheKomodo I have edited the missing html for the second slider into your html (with comments, easy to find). Now you must look how many images with filename `c` (c1, c2, ...) you have and set that number to `var slider2 = slide('c', speed, amount of images)`.

Comment: It works. Thank you so very much as I was just not able to get it to do it